# Java WAR file deployment issue

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, war, 7zip

we are trying to replace a class file in the WAR using 7-zip.
While redeploying the WAR in jboss server we are facing bean exception error.Any help on this...

*"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Project: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myMethod' defined in class path resource*

This WAR is working fine without any code change. We added one line change in a java file and compiled it. when we tried to replace the class file and deploy we are facing this error.

Comment: How is the bean `myMethod` defined?

Comment: This WAR is working fine without any code change... We added a one line change in a java file and compiled it... when we tried to replace the class file and deploy we faced this error...

Comment: Then please add that line before and after change to the question

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by using Winzip instead of 7-zip... Looks like the 7-zip compression technique is not compatible with jboss-eap-7.0.9.CP